# Select when devise send the confirmation mail or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

i need to select when devise send the confirmation mail. I overwrite the send_confirmation_instructions and add a date field named invited on my user model. If the invited field is null send the mail, otherwise not sent.

**Here's my code:**

```
  def send_confirmation_instructions
    unless invited.nil?
      self.confirmation_token = nil if reconfirmation_required?
      @reconfirmation_required = false
      generate_confirmation_token! if self.confirmation_token.blank?
    else
      self.confirmation_token = nil if reconfirmation_required?
      @reconfirmation_required = false
      generate_confirmation_token! if self.confirmation_token.blank?
      self.devise_mailer.confirmation_instructions(self).deliver
    end
  end
```

**The output of my console its:**

> Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.10)
>   1.9.3-p0 :001 > User.create!(:email => "hello@test.com") NoMethodError: undefined method `reconfirmation_required?' for

I have rewrite many other devise method without problems. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is reconfirmation_required? defined?  Also the entire console error would be more helpful if it included the class that is trying to call reconfirmation_required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to connect manually to the database and add the fields to the users table.

```
# read configuration from database.yml
config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
host = config["host"]
database = config["database"]
username = config["username"]
password = config["password"]

# stablish db connection
mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => host, :username => username, :database => database, :password => password)

# generate devise confirmation token
token = (Digest::MD5.hexdigest "#{ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(10)}-#{DateTime.now.to_s}")

# made the sql
sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, confirmation_token, confirmation_sent_at) VALUES ('email@test.com', '#{token}', '#{Time.now.to_s}')"

# execute query
mysql.query(sql)

# close mysql connection
mysql.close
```

I hope this will be useful.